# RSpec Controller Test: No Route Matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Here's my error msg:

```
 1) VisitorSessionsController (1) Actions (a) #record params('view') has http success
     Failure/Error: expect ( get :record ).to have_http_status(:success)
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"record", :controller=>"visitor_sessions"}
```

No route matches. I've tried several ways to alleviate this error, but first, take a look at the controller action:

```
  def record
    case params[:visitor_action]
      when 'view'
        impression = @visitor_session.impressions.create( ad_id: @ad.id )
        impression.start
      when 'click'
        @visitor_session.clicks.create( time: Time.now, ad_id: @ad.id )
    end
    render nothing: true
  end
```

Here's the few ways I've tried to overcome the route matches issue:

```
 describe "params('view')" do 
    it "has http success" do
        #get :record, { :visitor_session => "view" }
        #expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
        #expect ( get :record ).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
 end
```

Yet all these return the same error, "no route matches". What's going on here that I'm missing?

EDIT: Relevant route:

```
get 'record/:visitor_action/:visitor_session_token/:ad_token', to: 'visitor_sessions#record', as: :record_action
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant routes?

Comment: Added the only route related to the action in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide all of the parameters defined in your route OR redefine your route to make them optional.  The reason it can't match the route is because you're not providing `:visitor_action`, `:visitor_session_token` or `:ad_token` in your request.  You can make them optional like so:

> get 'record/(:visitor_action/(:visitor_session_token/(:ad_token)))', to: 'visitor_sessions#record', as: :record_action

Comment: You should note that in the above route the parameters are nested in such a way that you can provide nothing, just `:visitor_action`, `:visitor_action` and `:visitor_session_token` OR all three.  That is to say that you cannot provide a downstream parameter without also providing the upstream parameters (ie. you cannot provide `:visitor_session_token` but not `:visitor_action`).  Just a heads up.